# PHP filesize if-statement still executes even when false

Tags: php, file-writing

```
<?php
$seatsArray = array();
$myFile = fopen("seats.txt", "w") or die("Unable to Open File!");
if(filesize("seats.txt") == 0) {
    for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
        fwrite($myFile, "0\n");
    }
}   
$seatsArray = file("seats.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
fclose($myFile);
?>

var array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $seatsArray ).'"' ?>];
```

This PHP code is at the top of my script section in head. The seats.txt file is full of zeroes initially to represent vacant seats on a flight and through other functions, the seats will fill up (represented by 1s). I can get the 1s to write to the file but as soon as I reload the page, the if-statement seems to execute regardless of its condition being false and resets everything back to zero.

Comment: No, `filesize` [returns the boolean false](http://php.net/filesize), while you're doing `if(filesize("seats.txt") == 0)`. You're doing a loose comparison, which will equate to `true`, as in `false == 0`, which, in this context, is `true`. You need to use `===` for strict type comparison. As the manual states `$a === $b  Identical  TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type. ` The `same type` part here is very very important.

Comment: actually the link that you provided says that it returns a `int`

Comment: _Returns the size of the file in bytes, or FALSE (and generates an error of level E_WARNING) in case of an error._

Comment: But I do not see the point in checking the file size of a file that has just been opened for writing. Opening for writing will truncate the file to zero length. Move the `fopen` inside the branch?

Comment: do you need to append your new value in files right ?

Comment: @Andrew if the file exists it would return 0, false would return only if there is an error - like for example the file not existing. In this case fopen will create a file with 0 size so `filesize` should return a 0 int value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is due to this `w mode`

```
w- (Write only. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a new file if it doesn't exist)
```

So every time your `file` gets `blank`

Use `a` or `a+` if you want to `append` at the right of `file` or `r+` if you want to right from starting

Comment: Replaced it with r+ and it's working as intended now. Thank  you.

Comment: @Guy Fieri Welcome if it worked then mark it your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand you correctly, but I think you only want to write the file if it does not exist:

```
<?php
$seatsArray = array();
if(!file_exists("seats.txt") || filesize("seats.txt") == 0) {
    $myFile = fopen("seats.txt", "w") or die("Unable to Open File!");
    for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
        fwrite($myFile, "0\n");
    }
    fclose($myFile);
}   
$seatsArray = file("seats.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
?>

var array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $seatsArray ).'"' ?>];
```

Additionally, I would recommend putting the filename into a constant, which reduces the risk of typos (so PHP will complain, if it encounters an undefined constant in case of a typo).